# while saving crystal report showing file save failed in visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

am working on visual studio 2010 and sap crystal report..
most of the time while i am saving my crystal report i am getting error "

> File Save Failed

"[image]

then every time I used to re- open my project ,,this is only happening when ever i am working on crystal reports.if i am try to save anything after doing some work,,this message box will come
why always i am getting this error? how i can resolve this issue??

if any one know please help me.

Comment: Have yo checked to see if the file location it wants to save in exists? If it does, are there any permissions issues? Also, save the report in a different location (File -> Save xxx.rpt as), then close it and try to reopen.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but it looks to me like the file is set to read-only.

Comment: not set any file read only